# Proof verification: Show that the intersection of two generators is a subgroup of both individual generators.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

Can someone please verify whether my proof is logically correct? :) Note that it is not assumed that $\left \langle a\right \rangle \cap \left \langle b\right \rangle=\left \{ e \right \}$.

> If $a$ and $b$ are generators of a group $G$, then show that $\left \langle a\right \rangle \cap \left \langle b\right \rangle$ is a subgroup of both $\left \langle a\right \rangle$ and $\left \langle b\right \rangle$.

**Proof:**

Let $\left \langle a \right \rangle \cap \left \langle b \right \rangle =\left \{ c^{k}:c^{k}\in \left \langle a \right \rangle,\left \langle b \right \rangle \right \}$.

Since $e\in \left \langle a \right \rangle$ and $e\in \left \langle b \right \rangle$, then $e\in \left \langle a \right \rangle \cap \left \langle b \right \rangle$ by definition.

Let $c^{k},c^{m}\in \left \langle a \right \rangle \cap \left \langle b \right \rangle$. Then $c^{k},c^{m}\in \left \langle a \right \rangle $ and $c^{k},c^{m}\in \left \langle b \right \rangle $. Then $c^{k}(c^{m})^{-1}=c^{k}c^{-m}=c^{k-m}\in \left \langle a \right \rangle \cap \left \langle b \right \rangle$, since $c^{k}(c^{m})^{-1}=c^{k}c^{-m}=c^{k-m}\in \left \langle a \right \rangle, \left \langle b \right \rangle$. Therefore, $\left \langle a \right \rangle \cap \left \langle b \right \rangle \leq \left \langle a \right \rangle$ and $\left \langle a \right \rangle \cap \left \langle b \right \rangle \leq \left \langle b \right \rangle$. $\square$

Comment: Why you you define $\left \langle a \right \rangle \cap \left \langle b \right \rangle =\left \{ c^{k}:c^{k}\in \left \langle a \right \rangle,\left \langle b \right \rangle \right \}$?

Comment: @Carl I don't know. I thought it would make things easier for me to understand. Is it wrong?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense.  What is $c$?  Just any element of $G$?  Why do you care that $c^k$ is in $\langle a \rangle$?  Also the notation is ambiguous, is it supposed to be contained in both $\langle a \rangle$ and $\langle b \rangle$?  If so, why not just say $c^k \in \langle a \rangle \cap \langle b \rangle$

Comment: the proof is fine. it could be written up more concisely, but that's a little nitpicky, especially since this is probably for a first course in abstract algebra.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, then $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of both $H$ and $K$. The fact that $H$ and $K$ are generated by a single element is irrelevant.